# SSL Certificate Configuration Error on XAMPP server

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl, apache2, xampp

I have been following [this](https://www.bizmate.biz/articles-mainmenu-2/18-little-it-tricks/48-ssl-virtualhost-apache2-xampp) guide in order to configure SSL certificate on XAMPP server where I have enabled SSL on 4433 (as well as 443 after encoutering errors but no result, below config and error is against 443) port. I have created a certificate and kept common name in it as 'mydomain'. This is how my httpd-vhosts.conf file looks like

```
 #NameVirtualHost mydomain

<VirtualHost mydomain:8888>  
DocumentRoot C:\xampp\htdocs\mydomain  
ServerName mydomain  
    <Directory C:\xampp\htdocs\mydomain>     
                AllowOverride All     
                Allow from All  
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost mydomain:443> 
DocumentRoot C:\xampp\htdocs\mydomain 
ServerName mydomain
<Directory C:\xampp\htdocs\mydomain> 
 AllowOverride All 
 Allow from All 
</Directory> 
 SSLEngine on 
 SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL 
SSLCertificateFile "conf\ssl.crt\mydomain.crt" 
SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf\ssl.key\mydomain.key" 
<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|pl|asp|php)$"> 
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars 
</FilesMatch>
<Directory "C:\xampp\cgi-bin">
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>
BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0 
</VirtualHost>
```

I have also made changes in httpd-ssl.conf file accordingly

```
#General setup for the virtual host
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/mydomain"
ServerName mydomain
ServerAdmin admin@mydomain
ErrorLog "C:/xampp/apache/logs/error.log"
TransferLog "C:/xampp/apache/logs/access.log"

 ....
 SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/mydomain.crt"
```

But no matter what I do, I an unable to get away with this error;

```
[Thu Dec 13 13:56:25.779456 2018]    [core:notice] [pid 5868:tid 400] AH00094:  Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Thu Dec 13 13:56:25.779456 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5868:tid 400] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 1940
[Thu Dec 13 13:56:26.231857 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 1940:tid 416] AH01909: mydomain:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Dec 13 13:56:26.231857 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 1940:tid 416] AH01909: mydomain:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Dec 13 13:56:26.419057 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 1940:tid 416] AH01909: mydomain:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Dec 13 13:56:26.419057 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 1940:tid 416] AH01909: mydomain:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
```

I have `Run as Administrator` but no progress. My `servername` and `Common name` in cerificate are both same. Can someone suggest what else is required to make ssl certificate work on XAMPP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/578061/rsa-certificate-configured-for-server-does-not-include-an-id-which-matches-the-s

Comment: Thanks @garethTheRed, I recovered from this error, now error.log is not showing any of it but still my TLS handshake gets timeout.

Comment: Check your firewalls?

Comment: Yeah I did allow communication on specified ports but still connection gets timedout. There is no error in logs either.

Comment: Have you set the `Listen` directive to the correct port?  It's not shown above.

Comment: yeah it is fine. I found a solution to a part of problem, by using `<VirtualHost *:443>` instead of `<VirtualHost mydomain:443>`. and modifying  DocumentRoot and Directory to C:/xampp/htdocs. With these changes I have managed to start secure communication with xampp but problem is still there as I am unable to access my site (mydomain within htdocs) with https.