# Using HTTPS on an Apache server won't work

Tags: apache2

For my server, www.tripmatcher,com, I am having the same issue as [Why does apache httpd tell me that my name-based virtualhosts only works with SNI enabled browers (RFC 4366)](https://serverfault.com/questions/434599/why-does-apache-httpd-tell-me-that-my-name-based-virtualhosts-only-works-with-sn).  My config file lives at /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf, and looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerName tripmatcher.com
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^tripmatcher.com
        RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.tripmatcher.com/$1 [L,R=301]

        ServerAdmin admin@tripmatcher.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        <Directory "/var/www/html">
        AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
       # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example # the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

ServerAdmin admin@tripmatcher.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/html
<Directory "/var/www/html">
        AllowOverride All
        </Directory>


ServerName tripmatcher.com

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

SSLEngine on

SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/tripmatcher.crt

SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/tripmatcher.key

SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/tripmatcher.ca-bundle

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

As far as I can see, this looks fine.  Would anyone point out to me what is going wrong?  The issue is when I go to https://www.tripmatcher.com, I get the page loading, albeit with some CSS missing.  However, when I log in and go to, say https://tripmatcher.com/matcher I get 'The requested URL /matcher was not found on this server.'  Would someone please explain to me what's going wrong?

[Sun Dec 10 22:23:25.578086 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 19647] AH02292: Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Sun Dec 10 22:23:25.580546 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 19647] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20 OpenSSL/1.0.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Dec 10 22:23:25.580590 2017] [core:notice] [pid 19647] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

I see that in the logs.

Comment: There's two separate issues here: a 404, and a warning in your logs.  Which one do you want help with?

Comment: The 404. I thought the two might be connected.

Comment: You may want to reformulate your question, in particular the title, to make that clear.

Comment: Also, please post the HTTPS vhost.

Comment: Which one, the /etc/hosts?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts

Comment: If so, it looks like that.

Comment: According to the original question, may I troll a little bit? Use NginX :) I personally think it works better than Apache. Plut it has a built-in loadbalancer and that saved me a million of workhours (not literary) for my webapplications. Plus it is quite easy to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

Simply changing the top of my .htaccess did the trick:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.tripmatcher.com/index.php/$1 [R,L]
#RewriteRule
```

Hopefully that's useful for anyone else having this issue.